# Pasar código HTML (estructura y contenido) a una tabla mysql en php

Tags: php

Quiero pasar código HTML a una tabla de MySQL. Por ejemplo:

```
$dato = "<p>Hola mundo <a href='#'> Click </a></p>";
```

Cuando inserto este código a la tabla de MySQL me lo procesa automáticamente. Es decir, sale el texto únicamente y lo que necesito es que me salga tal cual está, con la `<p>` de párrafo y la `<a>` de enlace y sus correspondientes cierres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás enviando el contenido tal cual al navegador, y eso hará que éste lo interprete como HTML.

Para evitarlo debes usar la función [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) para convertir los caracteres especiales de HTML en entidades para que el contenido del texto pueda ser mostrado en el navegador tal cual:

```
<?php
$dato = "<p>Hola mundo <a href='#'> Click </a></p>";
echo htmlspecialchars($dato);
```

Mostrará en el navegador el texto correctamente, pero si miras el código fuente del HTML verás esto:

```
&lt;p&gt;Hola mundo &lt;a href=&#039;#&#039;&gt; Click &lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```